# Is swipe to archive possible with non-Gmail account in iOS?

Tags: ios, email

Is it possible to configure which folder to put mail in when swiping on a email to archive/delete with a non-Gmail account?

My objective with this would be to file email into an archive more easily than tapping Edit->Move->ArchiveFolder. This is currently possible when you set up a Gmail account on your device but not with other accounts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can now be accomplished very easily in iOS 7.

*(n.b. The following assumes that you have already setup your account on the iOS device. These steps described are for a generic IMAP account. Also, when ALL CAPS are used below, it is to reflect how Apple has it listed in iOS 7.)*

1. Launch the 'Settings' app on your iOS device
2. Scroll down and then tap on "Mail, Contacts, Calendars"
3. Tap on the email account you want to configure.
4. Tap on the 'Account' line with the `>` at the top of the next screen
5. On the 'IMAP ACCOUNT INFORMATION' screen, scroll all the way down until you see 'Advanced' and tap on it
6. Now you will see a 'MAILBOX BEHAVIORS' screen, showing you which mailboxes are used for Drafts, Sent, Deleted, and Archive mailboxes.
7. **Important:** Tap on the 'Archive Mailbox' line and verify that you have chosen the correct folder *on the server* where you want messages to be saved.
8. Once you have verified that the Archive Mailbox points to where you want it to go, look for the 'MOVE DISCARDED MESSAGES INTO' section, and tap 'Archive Mailbox' (instead of 'Deleted Mailbox')
9. **Important:** These changes ***will not be saved*** until you properly exit the configuration screen. To do this, tap the '`<` Account button near the top of the 'Advanced' screen.
10. When you get back to the 'Account' screen, tap 'Done' at the top-right corner.

If you'd like a step-by-step guide with screenshots, I have created one and made it available at: http://share.luo.ma/TUAW/guides/Archive-Email-Instead-of-Deleting.pdf

Comment: Thanks for updating with new information after the iOS 7 update. I did wonder whether this was going to be implemented for accounts other than the 'gmail' type account.

Comment: Thanks for step 9 (exiting configuration screen).  I'm so used to all settings taking effect immediately that I couldn't figure out what went wrong

Comment: @huyz - YUP. The same thing kept happening to me, which is why I mentioned it. If you try to install a personal certificate for email accounts you might run into the same thing. I'm not used to having to 'save' preferences, especially going BACK to a previous screen. Very non-intuitive.

Comment: URL in answer is dead

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for an answer to that for some time now. So far the only suggestion I was told was to try Sparrow for iOS, which does just that

Answer (score 0):

First change the location of deleted items for the non-Gmail account, under `Settings > Mail > Account > Advanced`. Afterwards, when you swipe and Delete, the "deleted" messages should go to your selected folder.